# Write in database via PHP - MySQL - Android

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to write into my database which is located on my server. Select-Statements work totally fine, but I want to create a new entry in the table. I use the INSERT for this and did it this way:

Java Code (of App/Client):

```
        //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idNumber.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameText.getText().toString()));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://olli130.myds.me/sqlcreate.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.i("Sent to Server", "name: " + nameText.getText().toString() + ", id: " + idNumber.getText().toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

And the PHP Code:

```
<?php
include 'sqlcon.php';

    $connection=mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die
    ("Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen");

    mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Konnte die Datenbank nicht
    waehlen.");

     $sql = "INSERT INTO Testtable (id, descr)
     VALUES (".$_REQUEST['id']", '".$_REQUEST['name']"')";

     mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Am i doing something badly wrong? Why is it not working?

Comment: Try `VALUES ('" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['name'] . "')` instead. You left out a few dots and quotes.

Comment: Thank you - I changed it. But it is still not working

Comment: You're welcome. How are you defining `$mysqldb`? In your `sqlcon.php` file?

Comment: like this: $mysqldb="Programdata"; I am using the sqlcon.php in two other files which are working fine. I am new to PHP and i dont know what is wrong here, seems ok to me as a newbie :/

Comment: And the form you're using, both fields are "named"? I.e. `<input type="text" name="id">` and  `<input type="text" name="name">` and matching columns in your DB?

Comment: The names are matching to the columns in my DB. But where do i have to define a form? The types are integer for id and varchar for name

Comment: How is the information entered, via a form? There might be something I'm not aware of, in using JAVA code. And, was it working for you before?

Comment: This code is from an android app. The data entered via two inputfields as Strings. No, INSERTING hasn't worked yet..

Comment: Try `VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $name . "')` see if that will work. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: I solved the problem - It's a shame. I forgot one " in the PHP File above which means that the INSERT has never been executed because it was qouted :D thank you very much!

Comment: Well I'm glad you were able to figure out what the problem was, cheers :)